# Strong type (newtype) generalized

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement "strong type", i.e newtype carrying *metier* information , as in this code snippet

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class UnderlyingTypeable a  b where 
 get :: a -> b

newtype Voltage = Voltage Double deriving (Show,Read,Num, Eq,Ord)
instance UnderlyingTypeable Voltage Double where
 get(Voltage v) = v

newtype Resistance = Resistance Double deriving (Show,Read,Num, Eq,Ord)
instance UnderlyingTypeable Resistance Double where
 get(Resistance r) = r

newtype Ampere = Ampere Double deriving (Show,Read,Num, Eq,Ord)
instance UnderlyingTypeable Ampere Double where
 get(Ampere a) = a


v1 = Voltage 15
v2 = Voltage 21
--works nicely. 
sum = v1 + v2

r = Resistance 10

-- does not compile. Great.
--foo = v1/r  

--Works ok. We got "strong type" that prevent adding cabbage and carot unless explicitly said..
i = Ampere $ (get v1) / (get r)
```

All that works ok. And can work with different underlying type.

Now I am struggly to generalize :

How to define the "default" implementation for the get function ? (to avoid the very repetitive and dull explicit instances)

Second question (more theoratical) . I did spend some time before finding that I need to activate `{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}`  to have the type class declaration ok.
 is there a list of language extensions safely activable t ? - by safely I mean that they should not break code not using it and they should not overlap themselve

Comment: Maybe try googling "safe coercions". Most GHC extensions are harmless and can be activated without causing too many issues. Some (actually, many) should be on by default, IMO. The only ones I'd try to avoid are overlapping / incoherent instances. I can't think of anything else to avoid right now.

Comment: IIUC, `deriving Num` is probably not right. In particular, it is going to let you multiply two voltages and get back another voltage! I've heard that the [`units`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/units) package solves this kind of problem nicely though.

Comment: Cf. lens package too eg. `Wrapped` `_Unwrapped'` `makeWrapped`, it's advanced but useful

Answer (score 3):

As @chi noted in a comment, GHC has a concept of "safe coercions" using the `coerce` function from `Data.Coerce`.  The actual rules are a little complicated, but simplifying somewhat, `coerce` can be used to convert between two types with the same representation, and each `newtype` has the same representation as its underlying type and so can be safely coerced to its underlying type (or from its underlying type):

```
i = Ampere $ coerce v1 / coerce r
```

Given this, you might not even need your `UnderlyingTypeable` class, and can just use `coerce` directly.  However, if you do still want it, then the following ought to provide a reasonable default:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

import Data.Coerce

class UnderlyingTypeable a  b where 
 get :: a -> b
 default get :: Coercible a b => a -> b
 get = coerce
```

To answer your second question, the folks at FP Complete (makers of Stack, among other things), include a list of recommended extensions as part of their RIO project.  See the [README](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/rio).  They are chosen on the basis that they are well accepted by the Haskell community, are unlikely to break anything, and are generally considered safe.

Comment: The problem with using `coerce` directly is it will *also* happily convert `Resistance` to `Voltage`, etc. Which is fine and correct as far as "these types have the same representation" goes, but being too liberal with using `coerce` directly can lead to effective loss of the type safety you were trying to create by using newtypes instead of using the representations directly. My usual principle is that I love `coerce` for *implementing* an API, but I don't want it to be a normal part of my toolkit when I'm using that API.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of packages like [newtype-generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-generics), [coercible-utils](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/coercible-utils) and [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) (the [`Control.Lens.Wrapped`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.1/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html) module) which provide an api for working with newtypes, with uniform packers and unpackers, among other features.

For example, using [`unpack`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/coercible-utils-0.1.0/docs/CoercibleUtils-Newtype.html#v:unpack) from coercible-utils:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import CoercibleUtils.Newtype
import GHC.Generics

newtype Voltage = Voltage Double deriving (Show,Read,Eq,Ord,Generic)

newtype Resistance = Resistance Double deriving (Show,Read,Eq,Ord,Generic)

i = Ampere $ unpack v1 / unpack r
```

`unpack` has a [`Newtype`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/coercible-utils-0.1.0/docs/CoercibleUtils-Newtype.html#t:Newtype) constaint. According to the documentation:

> The version of the Newtype class exported by this module has an
>   instance for *all* and *only* newtypes with Generic instances whose
>   generated Coercible instances are visible. Users need not, and
>   probably should not, write their own instances.

So, it seems that it's enough to derive `Generic` for our newtypes, and ensure that the constructor is in scope (for the `Coercible` instance).